# Can't restore Firefox Session

Tags: firefox

This is not a programming question.
My firefox just crashed and it won't restore previous session. It opens with this `about:sessionrestore` on the  URL. I get a alert box with `"The URL is not valid and cannot be loaded."`

Wondering if anyone has seen this before and how to manually restore the closed  sessions. I'm using the latest version of Firefox 9.0.1.

Thanks

Comment: While a good question, this is *probably* a better fit on [su].

Comment: Obvious answer - have you tried re-installing it? A new version of FF has only just been released :)

Comment: "This is not a programming question." This is probably a sign that you're asking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.  From experimenting, it looks like the problem is in the sessionstore.js itself.  You can try renaming sessionstore.bak to sessionstore.js and see if that will open but given the behaviour of Firefox, it might be too late already.  It is in my case.